# R code to read table, perform calculations, and write excel

Tags: beginner, excel, r

I hear loops are best avoided in R.

Is there a better way to do something like this perhaps using lapply, etc.?

```
library(xlsx)

files <- list.files(path="/tmp/data", pattern="*.xls", full.names=T, recursive=TRUE)

for(i in 1:length(files)) {
  df <- read.table(files[i], header=TRUE)
  avgArea <- mean(df[df$Area>20,"Area"])
  avgMean <- mean(df[df$Area>20,"Mean"])
  fnNew <- paste(tools::file_path_sans_ext(files[i]), ".xlsx", sep="")
  wb <- createWorkbook(type="xlsx")
  sheet  <- createSheet(wb, sheetName="data")
  addDataFrame(df, sheet)
  rows  <- createRow(sheet, rowIndex=nrow(df)+1)
  cells <- createCell(rows, colIndex=1:4)
  setCellValue(cells[[1,2]], "Average")
  setCellValue(cells[[1,3]], avgArea)
  setCellValue(cells[[1,4]], avgMean)
  saveWorkbook(wb, fnNew)
}
```

An example .xls can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uehkyjcocrs5jgq/Image1_results.xls?dl=1)

Comment: If you can share the Excel file or another file so that we can run your code that would be helpful.

Comment: added a .xls example

Comment: Are you sure your code does something more than creating a xlsx copy of the xls files ? After running your code I don't see `"Average"` anywhere in the xlsx file.

Comment: Here you are looking over files.  Since file IO overhead likely dominates loop overhead, I don't think there is any problem at all with the loop.  Maybe if you have tens of thousands of files you would see a tiny speedup with some other approach.